# Error attempting to deserialize a Json object to use a sub-object's data as the parent-object's primary key

Tags: android, serialization, gson, retrofit, realm

I am trying to deserialize the Meh.com json object. The way it's set up, there is no good primary key. I hoped to use the DealID (which is a unique string) as the primary key of my "Current" realm objects. But my deserializer appears to not be working as I expected, because the primary key is null. Also, the debugging code I put (the log) says "DEAL ID: null". Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks. (By the way, I am using retrofit too, but the code for retrofit is omitted. Please let me know if you think you need to see it.)

By the way, this code has been working before. Before, I was using integer primary keys that are auto-generated. So, I know that the internet connection works, etc. But the only issue here is when I tried to add this deserializer.

Here is my deserializer code:

```
public class CurrentDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Current>
{
    public Current deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        Deal deal = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject(), Deal.class);
        Poll poll = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject(), Poll.class);
        Video video = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject(), Video.class);
        Log.e("CurrentDeserializer", "DEAL ID: " + deal.getId());
        return new Current(deal, poll, video, deal.getId());
    }
}
```

Current.java:

```
public class Current extends RealmObject
{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String primaryKey;
    private Deal deal;
    private Poll poll;
    private Video video;

    public Current()
    {

    }
    public Current(Deal deal, Poll poll, Video video, String primaryKey)
    {
        this.deal = deal;
        this.poll = poll;
        this.video = video;
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }
    //Getters & setters
}
```

Deal.java:

```
public class Deal extends RealmObject
{
    private String features;
    private String id;
    private RealmList<Item> items;
    private RealmList<URL> photos;
    private String title;
    private Date soldOutAt;
    private String specifications;
    private Story story;
    private Theme theme;
    private String url;
    private Topic topic;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Gson code:

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Color.class, new ColorDeserializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Current.class, new CurrentDeserializer());
    Type token = new TypeToken<RealmList<URL>>(){}.getType();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(token, new TypeAdapter<RealmList<URL>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, RealmList<URL> value) throws IOException
        {
            // Ignore
        }

        @Override
        public RealmList<URL> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException
        {
            RealmList<URL> list = new RealmList<URL>();
            in.beginArray();
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                list.add(new URL(in.nextString()));
            }
            in.endArray();
            return list;
        }
    });
    gsonBuilder.setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f)
        {
            return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary key value must not be null.
E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.CurrentRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(CurrentRealmProxy.java:308)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1580)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:1148)
```

Json:

```
{
  "deal": {
    "features": "- Two WiFi-enabled video cameras that look enough like Apple stuff not to blow your cred\r\n- Unlike the last Izons we sold, these have night vision so they work after dark (sultry sax solo not included)\r\n- Watch and record from your phone, as if you need one more excuse to stare at your phone\r\n- When the sound and/or motion detectors detect sound and/or motion, they send you an alert and start recording video of the detected sound and/or motion\r\n- Model: WRM-WA3-00, WRM-BA3-00",
    "id": "a6k31000000PBuPAAW",
    "items": [
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "Color",
            "value": "White"
          }
        ],
        "condition": "New",
        "id": "103691",
        "price": 68,
        "photo": "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486235/fny7l3yvsxi4k1l4ixxd.png"
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "Color",
            "value": "Black"
          }
        ],
        "condition": "New",
        "id": "103692",
        "price": 68,
        "photo": "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446485970/o2iruukbyarxwj9swzmj.png"
      }
    ],
    "photos": [
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446485970/o2iruukbyarxwj9swzmj.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486235/fny7l3yvsxi4k1l4ixxd.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446513996/bu4wmzkmagruhcgup4mm.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486118/plqodhmrvpepzbejowps.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486160/ufnnqid6urlabeefnohu.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486802/qqhjczfqrpno4twzryr4.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486854/dwnvyf8crzwbeuuvuxix.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486897/udajgt5bqns7f4rdrexz.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446516494/hpwolr7cnolknhouter6.gif"
    ],
    "title": "2-for-Tuesday: Stem Izon View Wi-Fi Video Monitors",
    "specifications": "Specs \r\n====\r\n- Model: WRM-BA3-00, WRM-WA3-00\r\n- Compatible with iOS 5.0 and higher, and Android 4.2 and higher\r\n- Camera pivots on magnetic base that can be mounted on walls or ceilings\r\n- 60Â° viewing angle\r\n- Auto or manual Night Vision\r\n- Requires a WiFi connection\r\n- Powered via mini USB (8 ft cord included)\r\n- View up to 10 monitors from your device\r\n- Dimensions: 5\" height x 2\" width\r\n- Intended for indoor use between 14Â° and 131Â° F\r\n- 802.11g wireless connection required (recommended 802.11n wireless connection with at least 2Mbps upload speed)\r\n- 2.4 GHz bandwidth\r\n- Video: QVGA 10 frames per second\r\n- App bitsream: 300kbps\r\n- Motion and noise detection start 5 seconds before the event, end 5 seconds after, and record up to 30 seconds\r\n- Audio: mono 40 Hz - 8 kHz, 16kHz sample rate\r\n- Noise detection: 35dB to 95dB\r\n- [User guide](http://www.izoncam.com/file/2014/06/IZON-iew-US_EU-User-Guide.pdf)\r\n- [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steminnovation.izon)\r\n- [Android app guide](http://www.izoncam.com/izon-app-guide-android/)\r\n- [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/izon/id549682052)\r\n- [iOS app guide](http://www.izoncam.com/izon-app-guide/)\r\n\r\n**Condition:** New \r\n**Warranty:** [1 Year Stem](http://www.izoncam.com/file/2014/06/IZON-iew-US_EU-User-Guide.pdf) \r\n**Estimated Delivery:** 11/11 - 11/13\r\n**Shipping:** $5 or free with **[VMP](https://mediocre.com/vmp)**\r\n\r\nWhat's in the Box?\r\n====\r\n2x Izon View camera\r\n2x Magnetic base\r\n2x 8ft USB to Mini USB power cable\r\n2x USB power supply\r\n2x User manual\r\n\r\n\r\nPictures \r\n====\r\n[The options](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486397/oggl45a4sjevkaksjvo1.jpg)\r\n[Black in the box](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446485970/o2iruukbyarxwj9swzmj.png)\r\n[White in the box](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486235/fny7l3yvsxi4k1l4ixxd.png)\r\n[Black out of the box](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486118/plqodhmrvpepzbejowps.png)\r\n[White out of the box](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486160/ufnnqid6urlabeefnohu.png)\r\n[Connecting to phones and tablets](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486802/qqhjczfqrpno4twzryr4.png)\r\n[Everything included in one white unit](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486854/dwnvyf8crzwbeuuvuxix.png)\r\n[Everything included in one black unit](https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1446486897/udajgt5bqns7f4rdrexz.png)\r\n\r\nPrice Comparison\r\n====\r\n[$299.90 List, $169.98 (for 2) at Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Stem-White-Monitor-Surveillance-Android/dp/B00KMFKO04/?tag=meh0ec-20)\r\n\r\n*Find a relevant price comparison? Please share it in a comment in this thread :)*",
    "story": {
      "title": "Remember to secure your security camera.",
      "body": "It's ironic that some people can be so vigilant about physical security, and so lax about basic network security, that their pursuit of one compromises the other.\r\n\r\nTake this Stem Izon View security camera. It got built-in WiFi. It's got night vision. You can watch it through an app on your phone. When it detects sound or motion, it sends you an alert and starts recording video. Point it at the baby or dog or garage or convenience-store cash register of your choice and it'll do all the stuff a lot of fancier and more expensive cameras do. Don't you feel secure now?\r\n\r\nBut a couple of years ago, a security firm found that some people left their Stem Izon cameras [vulnerable](https://securityledger.com/2013/10/apple-store-favorite-izon-cameras-riddled-with-security-holes/) to hacks, because they (a) didn't use them with a router, (b) didn't change their default WiFi password, (c) didn't change their default router admin password, or (d) didn't change their default Izon camera password.\r\n\r\nThat's right: a security camera, improperly deployed, makes you *less* secure.\r\n\r\nJust do those four simple things, and you've won 99% of the battle of keeping your camera secure. If you're a hacker or a security expert, you already know nothing is ever completely free of any risk of hacking. But you don't have to outrun the bear, the saying goes; you just have to outrun the easiest pickings among your fellow prey. Very few bad guys will bother trying to vault your common-sense security measures when there are so many softer targets out there.\r\n\r\nIf those basic network security measures sound like too much hassle, don't get a WiFi security camera. You'll be more secure without it. Ironically."
    },
    "theme": {
      "accentColor": "#3f6a9b",
      "backgroundColor": "#c6cde5",
      "backgroundImage": null,
      "foreground": "dark"
    },
    "url": "https://meh.com/deals/2-for-tuesday--stem-izon-view-wi-fi-video-monitors",
    "topic": {
      "commentCount": 24,
      "createdAt": "2015-11-03T05:00:02.902Z",
      "id": "56383f520768092403885c4c",
      "replyCount": 17,
      "url": "https://meh.com/forum/topics/2-for-tuesday-stem-izon-view-wi-fi-video-monitors",
      "voteCount": 0
    }
  },
  "poll": {
    "answers": [
      {
        "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW-1",
        "text": "default",
        "voteCount": 23
      },
      {
        "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW-2",
        "text": "password",
        "voteCount": 23
      },
      {
        "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW-3",
        "text": "admin",
        "voteCount": 6
      },
      {
        "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW-4",
        "text": "public",
        "voteCount": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW-5",
        "text": "private",
        "voteCount": 45
      },
      {
        "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW-6",
        "text": "Something else, because you know how passwords are supposed to work",
        "voteCount": 385
      }
    ],
    "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW",
    "startDate": "2015-11-03T05:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "What is your home WiFi password?",
    "topic": {
      "commentCount": 17,
      "createdAt": "2015-11-03T05:00:02.509Z",
      "id": "56383f52d85612cc09d6d06e",
      "replyCount": 12,
      "url": "https://meh.com/forum/topics/what-is-your-home-wifi-password",
      "voteCount": 2
    }
  },
  "video": {
    "id": "a6l31000000TNvXAAW",
    "startDate": "2015-11-03T05:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Ask Irk: The Grateful Dead?",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ocr86btc2FE",
    "topic": {
      "commentCount": 12,
      "createdAt": "2015-11-02T04:59:59.838Z",
      "id": "5636edcf1469b5300aeff57d",
      "replyCount": 8,
      "url": "https://meh.com/forum/topics/ask-irk-the-grateful-dead",
      "voteCount": 9
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `Log.e("CurrentDeserializer", "DEAL ID: " + deal.getId());` ?

Comment: It is "DEAL ID: null".

Comment: Is it supposed to be `null`? As the exception said, the RealmObject's primary key cannot be `null` if you want to save it to the db. If it is `null`, then the Realm will be clue which record should be updated or should it just create a new record. When you are using `int` as the primary key before, it seems "working". But i think it didn't. It will create/update a `RealmObject` with id =0 which is a default value of int. If you change it to the boxed type `Integer`, I think it will fail as well. You have to set a proper primary key before save it to Realm.

Comment: I thought that this line of code `Deal deal = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject(), Deal.class);` would make `deal.getId()` no longer be null, but it's null. That is the main source of the problem, because I give the deal ID string to the Current constructor, which would set its primary key.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with you JSON input? Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, the JSON all downloads correctly eventually, and is displayed on the screen. It just appears to be null at this point in time in the code, and I don't know if that's expected behavior or not.

Comment: Posing your JSON input in the question would be helpful.

Comment: Ok I just added the JSON.

Comment: Can you please use debugger to check when `Deal deal = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject(), Deal.class);` is called, the `json.getAsJsonObject()` gives you the expected result?

Comment: I can't. I no longer have this code. I found a workaround, but I'm still interested in knowing the answer to this question though, so I am leaving this question up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94686/discussion-between-rock-lee-and-beeender).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I used for this issue is to use the Application class to get the context, and use the context to save my integers in the shared preferences. (I didn't know before that the context could be accessed from anywhere in the app.)

And I thought of another possibility, which is to simply create a dummy value for the primary key, and then edit it *right before* you call the "createOrUpdateRealmObject()" method.

I'm still interested in the real answer to this question, so I will ask a better question that duplicates the error in a simpler way, and post a link to it here.